# Selenium login script does not works for form using j_security_check

Tags: selenium-webdriver, j-security-check

I am trying to automate a login scenario which submit a form using j_security_check with selenium script

Below is the html code:

```
<form name="getuserin" action="j_security_check" method="POST">
<table width="45%" align="left">
   <tr>
      <td align="left">Uname</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td align="right">Passkey</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<br>
<center><input type="submit" name="action" value="Login"></center>
</form>
```

Selenium code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("validuser");
driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.name("action")).click();
```

Script runs successfully, with no error. The issue I am facing is there is not login action is performed while runnig the script, it does enter details and click the button. Whenever I try to login with the same credentials manually, it works! I have tried the scenario with Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Comment: Sorry a silly question: wasn't that j_security_check use j_username and j_password as the field's name ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a brake point after clicking on button and see if it logs in?

My suggestions are:

1. Maybe you close script before data is sent to the server.
2. Maybe you click on button before it's loaded.

In the second case you have to wait till page and all its scripts loaded. Before thinking how to do it try to set simple thread sleep for 2 seconds before clicking this button.

If it helps then you have to find out what handles this button and to wait till it's loaded.

Comment: The script is active after sending data to server. I've tried putting thread to sleep for upto 3 minutes, but none of them works. Tried putting break point as well, but no use. I am not getting anythig helping from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from itertools import cycle
import time
#importing various modules for added functionality



browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.example.com")
#creates browser object  
#b.o. makes GET request to specified site

username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")   
##looks for the html element "email" on above site
##looks for the html element "password" on above site



with open('creds.txt', 'r') as fp:
        credentials = [x.strip().split(':') for x in fp.readlines()]

for uname,pwd in cycle(credentials):

    username.send_keys(username from creds.txt file)
    password.send_keys(password from creds.txt file) 
    ##send username from file as email element value
    ##send password from file as password element value

    login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_id("signInBtn")
    login_attempt.click()
    ##looks for the html element "signInBtn" on above site
    ##simulates clicking of button

    time.sleep(2)

    title = browser.title
    print title
    #find the title of the html page and print it

    welcome = browser.find_element_by_id("specific_element")
    welcome_text = welcome.text.split()[1]
    read_welcome = welcome_text.encode('utf-8')
    #after successful login, look for element that is only present after successful login
    #Welcome, <name>; only want the name here
    #name was displaying in unicode for some reason, this converts the name as a normal string

    if 'specific_string' in title:
    #if string found in title variable
        print "Login Sucessful for %r " % read_welcome
        #"Login Successful for <name>"
        browser.get("http://www.link_to_sign_out")
        #simulate signing out


    elif 'specific_string' not in title:
    #if string not found in title variable
        print "Sign In failed.."  
        #"Sign In failed.."
        browser.get("http://www.link_to_sign_out")
        ##simulate signing out

    else:
        print 'Error..'
        #If neither condition is met "Error" is printed

    browser.close()
```